# WSO2 Enterprise Integrator v6.1.1-update 24 Error converting JSON to XML when JSON has array

Tags: json, xml, wso2-enterprise-integrator

Few days ago we switched to the WSO2 Enterprise Integrator version 6.1.1-update24 and services that have input payload a **JSON with array** now are getting the following error:

> TID: [-1234] [] [2018-10-22 15:45:11,954] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil} -  #toXml. Could not convert JSON Stream to XML. Cannot handle JSON input. Error>>> null {org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil}
>   TID: [-1234] [] [2018-10-22 15:45:11,954] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.PayloadFactoryMediator} -  Error converting JSON to XML, please check your JSON Path expressions return valid JSON:  {org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.PayloadFactoryMediator}
>   TID: [-1234] [] [2018-10-22 15:45:11,954] ERROR {API_LOGGER.UtilityAPI} -  Error converting JSON to XML, please check your JSON Path expressions return valid JSON:  {API_LOGGER.UtilityAPI}
>   TID: [-1234] [] [2018-10-22 15:45:11,974] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: /utility/testjsonarray,MessageID: urn:uuid:7bebe318-ff20-4126-8c1b-99600b6c276e,Direction: request,sequence = genericAPIFault,error_message = Error converting JSON to XML, please check your JSON Path expressions return valid JSON: ,error_code = 0,error_detail = org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error converting JSON to XML, please check your JSON Path expressions return valid JSON:
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator.handleException(AbstractMediator.java:327)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.PayloadFactoryMediator.replace(PayloadFactoryMediator.java:293)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.PayloadFactoryMediator.regexTransform(PayloadFactoryMediator.java:212)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.PayloadFactoryMediator.mediate(PayloadFactoryMediator.java:154)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.PayloadFactoryMediator.mediate(PayloadFactoryMediator.java:104)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:214)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
>           at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:351)
>           at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:399)
>           at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcess(RESTRequestHandler.java:123)
>           at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:101)
>           at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:69)
>           at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:303)
>           at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:92)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>           at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:331)
>           at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:377)
>           at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:149)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

To reproduce this error, from the carbon console create a REST API with following APIresource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/utility" name="UtilityAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/testjsonarray">
        <inSequence>
            <sequence key="inTestJsonArraySeq"/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

then add the following inSequence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="inTestJsonArraySeq" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log description="logInTest">
        <property name="sequence" value="inTestJsonArraySeq"/>
    </log>
    <payloadFactory description="pfJsonArrary" media-type="xml">
        <format>
            <myPayload xmlns="">$1</myPayload>
        </format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.myArray"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <respond description="respOut"/>
</sequence>
```

Call the REST API with the following JSON payload:

```
{
    "myArray" : ["element1", "element2", "element3"]
}
```

**NOTE1**: With WSO2 Enterprise Integrator v6.1.1 (no update) we do not experience this error, the response from the endpoint for the above payload is as expected:

```
<myPayload>
    <jsonElement>element1</jsonElement>
    <jsonElement>element2</jsonElement>
    <jsonElement>element3</jsonElement>
</myPayload>
```

Investigating the class that throws the error we noticed a version change for the synapse-commons library, from synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v15.jar (of WSO2EI v6.1.1) to  synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v44.jar (of WSO2 v6.1.1-update24) under {WSO2EI_HOME}/wso2/components/plugins/. This could be a clue for you guys from WSO2.

Answer (score 0):

Your aim is to convert json array to xml..so you should use property mediator for that 
For Example,

```
  <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/xml"/>
```

Hope this help.